# Numerical Integration with Inequality Condition

Tags: numerical-integration, inequalities

I need to solve the following definite integral:
$$\int_0^1 \mathrm{d}s \int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\phi \int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\phi' \int \mathrm{d}\theta\,'\sin{\theta\,'}  \text{,}$$

such that $$\theta_1 \leq \arctan{\frac{\sqrt{\cos^2{\theta\,'}+(s \sin{(\phi'-\phi)})^2\sin^2{\theta\,'}}}{\sqrt{1-(s \sin{(\phi'-\phi)})^2}\cdot\sin{\theta\,'}}} \text{ and } 0 \leq \theta\,'\leq\frac{\pi}{2} \text{,}$$

where $\theta_1$ is some given real number in $[0,\pi/2]$.

---

However, when I try to numerically solve this integral (with NSolve for the inequality condition) in Mathematica, with:

[image]

I get the following error:

[image]

It seems as though Mathematica wants to evaluate the inequality before actually feeding in the values of $s$,$\phi$, and $\phi'$ in the definite integral.

How can I numerically solve this integral--an integral with an inequality condition that cannot be simplified to lower bounds?

---

Mathematica Code:

```
θ1 = 1.183479725906243`;
NIntegrate[
  Sin[θp], {s, 0, 1}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {ϕp, 0, 2 π}, 
  θp ∈ 
    NSolve[
      {ArcTan[
         Sqrt[Cos[θp]^2 + (s Sin[ϕp - ϕ])^2 Sin[θp]^2] / 
           (Sqrt[1 - (s Sin[ϕp - ϕ])^2] Sin[θp])] >= θ1, 
       0 < θp < π/2}, 
      θp, Reals]];
```

Comment: You'll want to copy and paste your Mathematica code into your question, so that those who wish to try answering it don't have to retype it themselves. [And you're more likely to get help that way, since it makes it easier to work on the question.]

Comment: @theorist That's a good point; thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html):

```
NIntegrate[Sin[θp]
           Boole[
                 ArcTan[Sqrt[Cos[θp]^2 + (s Sin[ϕp - ϕ])^2 Sin[θp]^2]/(Sqrt[1 - (s Sin[ϕp - ϕ])^2] Sin[θp])] >= θ1
           ]
, {s, 0, 1}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {ϕp, 0, 2 π}, {θp, 0, π/2}]

(* 4.02185 *)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's so simple and makes a lot of sense, in hindsight.